# Calling a function inside a module

Tags: python-3.x

So, I made this module, and named it Dragon.

```
class Dragon:
        trapped = 0
        size = 0
        dragonName = 0
        def incounter(self):
            import random
            self.size = random.randrange(1,14)
            if self.size >10:
                return("It is arguably one of the most large dragon you've ever met in wild.")
            elif 11 > self.size >4:
                return("Its size is not notably small nor large. At best, its isn't remarkable.")
            else:
                return("Its size is remarkably small, even if you consider that it almost never had any compounds before.")
            self.dragonName = input('You decide to name it: ')
```

I imported it, and did

```
Mary = Dragon.Dragon
```

And then, did

```
Mary.incounter
```

Which gave me with blue

```
<function Dragon.incounter at 0x106098950>
```

And not what I should have got.

Can anyone help me with this problem, like, how to make it actually work?

If I am doing something wrong, please tell me. I am just a student who just got to know Python for three days.

Comment: What do you expect? May you forgot parenthesis twice? .. `Mary=Dragon.Dragon()` and `Mary.incounter()` .. does this answer your question?

Comment: Sorry for this, I really just started to learn Python. Yes, it did.

Comment: no problem, feel welcome